# Changing a dom element's position after load without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

hey i have some code that sets an elements style.width, height, and position
but its not working and I assumed it was because it was'nt in the head, but I want to change the css on like a mouseclick event so tabs will slide out and stuff but I'd rather not use jquery is there a way to do this?

edit: ok so Iv got the width and height problem solved exact it doesnt seem to respond when I try and position it

here's my code

```
for (i=1; i<=tab_array.length-1; i++)
{

    if (i==3)
    {
        document.getElementById("_"+i).style.cssText='height:'+Math.floor(p(100,gheight))+'px;'+
                                 'width:' +Math.floor(p(80,gwidth ))+'px;'+
                                 'background:black;'+
                                 'postion:absolute;'+
                                 'left:'+Math.floor(p(tab_array.across,gwidth)-gwidth)+'px;'
                                 ;
    }

    else
    {
        document.getElementById("_"+i).style.cssText='height:'+Math.floor(p(80,gheight))+'px;'+
                                 'width:' +Math.floor(p(80,gwidth ))+'px;';
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
function changeSize(id, height, width, interval){
  var es = E(id).style, h = parseInt(height), w = parseInt(width), f = Math.floor(h/w), n = parseInt(interval), i = 0;  
  var sit = setInterval(function(){
    i++; es.cssText = 'height:'+i*f+'px; width:'+i+'px;';
    if(i === w){
      es.cssText = 'height:'+h+'px; width:'+w+'px;'; clearInterval(sit); 
    }
  }, n);
}
changeSize('box', 100, 50, 20);
```

For the working example, visit http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/X6TMv/ . I did not add easing, which jQuery handles quite effectively though. I made the code to take Strings or Numbers from height on.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of i or the interval? @PHPglue

Comment: `SetInterval()` just keeps calling a function that is either passed as a String or an Anonymous Function. `i` has to increment up, so the size increases. Just calling `setInterval()` by itself will not automatically increase `i`. Notice the `i++;`? `i` is scoped within the `changeSize()` function starting at `i = 0`. `interval` is the milliseconds, or seconds/1000 which I stored in `n = parseInt(interval);`. I think you are not seeing the scroll bar. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp . Note that `self` is `window`, which is implicit.

Comment: I mean I just wanted to change the value, I have an outside function doing the incrementing, I tried `object.style.cssText='height:'+Math.floor(p(100,gheight))+'px;'` and that works fine except it doesnt work with `left:` for some reason I have a external css file stating the `position:absolute;` as well @PHPglue

Comment: To properly use `left:` you have to `position:relative;` the parent container, then `position:absolute;` the element you want to position. I would do this with the CSS. You can always change it with `element.style.left =` or use `element.style.cssText = 'left:'+yourLeftNum+'px; top:'+yourTopNum+'px;'`, later.

Comment: oops turns out I just forgot the `[i]` after `tab_array`